# Create Trigger after update in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables one is **MailAddress** & **BackupMailAddress** with same schema. I want to create a trigger which done the below activity in DB.

1)once Mail Status updated to "Send" in **MailAddress** Table. The same row should be inserted in **BackupMailAddress** Table.

2) Once row inserted in **BakcupMailAddress** Table successfully, same row should be deleted from **MailAddress** Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Trigger` should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insrt_mail_status
   BEFORE UPDATE OF MAIL_STATUS
   ON MAILADDRESS
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.MAIL_STATUS = 'Send')
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO BackupMailAddress (MAIL_STATUS, col1, col3)
        VALUES (:new.MAIL_STATUS, :new.col1, :new.col3);
END;
```

See Demo:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MAILADDRESS
(
   MAIL_STATUS   VARCHAR2 (10),
   col1          VARCHAR2 (10),
   col3          VARCHAR2 (10)
);

CREATE TABLE BackupMailAddress
AS
   SELECT * FROM MAILADDRESS;


SQL> SELECT * FROM MAILADDRESS;

MAIL_STATU COL1       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
Send       A          B

SQL> SELECT * FROM BackupMailAddress;

no rows selected

SQL> UPDATE MAILADDRESS
   SET MAIL_STATUS = 'Send';    

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM BackupMailAddress;

MAIL_STATU COL1       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
Send       A          B
```

Comment: Thanks for support its worked for me, Kindly help me to delete the record from main table after insertion in backup table.

Comment: @Jai. You can simply use delete statement to delete from the main table or you can write a procedure to do so. It cannot be done inside the trigger.